# AutoHotKey Loop ignores first line

Tags: loops, autohotkey

For some reason Autohotkey is ignoring the first line of code I have after I start my loop in a function called click_again. The goal is to have a repeat button clicked multiple times if the event is iterated.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? Please test anything you reply with, I have done a decent bit of troubleshooting to find this.

I don't see a bug reported about this and I've tried all sorts of things like adding braces {} for the if statement.

```
click_again(loopnumber){
if (%loopnumber% > 1)
    bug="arbitrary ignored line I have to add so that the loop runs"
    loopnumber-=1
    msgbox, %loopnumber%
    loop, %loopnumber%{
        click
        sleep, 1000
    }
}
```

The message box should show 1 less than the number that is passed in before it begins to loop. In the example I've given if I remove the bug assignment the number printed is the same as the number passed to the function. Meaning the shorthand subtract 1 is ignored instead. If you put in a msgbox for the value of bug it will print nothing.

Comment: can you specify at which position did you put the {} brace for the `if`

Comment: Remove the `%` around `loopnumber` in your if-statement. `If` automatically evaluates variables. https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IfExpression.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EJE got it right on the money, but didn't post the answer for some reason. If evaluates my input as a variable by default.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make it into an answer because (and I mean absolutely no offense or disrespect) I felt the question wasn't generally helpful to AHK users. In these cases, I still like to help out if possible, so I just leave a quick comment. I've seen in the past where some questions (and, subsequently, their answers) get deleted for being low quality or off topic (not at all saying yours is).

Comment: Not a problem. Right now it's trending about 1 view a day. I'll see how it goes.